# How to change 1 or 0, into a true or false output

Tags: c++

I have this hw assignment that I have completed. I am using a bool value in order for it to print 1 or 0. My question is how do I make it print out true or false, instead of the 1 or 0.

My output:

```
1 = true, 0 = false
------------
c1 >= c2 : 1
c1 <= c2 : 0
c1 != c2 : 1
c1 < c2 : 0
c1 > c2 : 1
c1 == c2 : 0
```

My code

```
int main() 
{

    //Declearing the radii of 2 circles in order to compare
    Circle c1(7);
    Circle c2(6);



    //prints true or false in boolean so 1 or 0

    bool compare;
    cout << "1 = true, 0 = false" << endl;
    cout << "------------" << endl;

    compare = c1 >= c2;
    cout<< "c1 >= c2 : "<< compare << endl;

    compare = c1 <= c2;
    cout<< "c1 <= c2 : "<< compare << endl;

    compare = c1 != c2;
    cout << "c1 != c2 : " << compare << endl;

    compare = c1 < c2;
    cout<< "c1 < c2 : " << compare << endl;

    compare = c1 > c2;
    cout << "c1 > c2 : " << compare << endl;

    compare = c1 == c2;
    cout << "c1 == c2 : " << compare << endl;
    cout << endl;
    

}
```

This is a multiple file program so I only added the main.cpp. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(compare ? "true":"false")`will work

Comment: @pm100 Make that an answer.

Comment: Another possibility is [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)

Comment: @pm100 I don't think that works. I am getting error 
"main.cpp:45:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]"

Comment: pm100 meant something like `cout<< "c1 >= c2 : "<< (compare ? "true" : "false") << endl;`, not `(compare ? "true":"false")` as a separate statement (which indeed wouldn't do anything).

Comment: std::string s[] = { "false", "true" }; std::cout << s[compare];

Comment: @AllanWind in that example, I would use `const char*` instead to avoid the overhead of creating unnecessary `std::string` objects: `const char* s[] = { "false", "true" };`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I actually wrote that up first, but figured the one-time overhead didn't matter much.  Update answer just for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we have some good options (ordered by time of submission):

1. `std::cout << (compare ? "true" : "false");`
2. `std::cout << std::boolalpha << compare;`
3. `const char *s[] = { "false", "true" }; std::cout << s[compare];`

Comment: And I would "vote for door #1" because it is **immediately obvious.** For either of the other two, if I encountered it somewhere in production code, "I would have to *think."* And in such situations I would rather not. **"Make your code *abundantly* clear."**

Comment: @MikeRobinson #2 respects the locale, and the other two don't. So there is definitely a case for using it.

Comment: I am quite fond of the tertiary operator, too, but the 2nd option would be the most succinct with repeated use like here.

Comment: I might even do this in c if I was in a hurry but it feels too dirty for c++: `const char *s = "false\0true"; size_t false_len = strlen(s) + 1; printf("%s", s + compare * false_len);`

Comment: One small argument against `std::boolalpha` is that is modifies the stream. In general, it would be preferable to leave the stream the way you found it. But saving and restoring this state is annoying, and quickly becomes an argument for option #1. That said, `boolalpha` itself is something you more typically want to leave enabled for a stream. But just for completeness, you can do `std::cout << (std::ostringstream() << std::boolalpha << compare).str()`. The simplest of course is just apply `boolalpha` at the beginning of the program and never touch it again.